# How do I extract images from a VB6 .frx file?

Tags: c#, vb6, resources, resx, vb6-migration

I'm converting some VB6 code to C#.  VB6 stores resources in a `.frx` file, the same way C# stores it in `.resx` files.  How do I convert the images in a `.frx` file into something that can be embedded in a `.resx` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the .frm file, it contains lines like this:

```
    Image = "blah.frx" : 1234
```

The string is the file (obviously), and the numbers are a hexadecimal offset to the image.  There's a 12 byte header at that location, and the last 4 bytes of that header contain the length of the image in bytes.  The image itself immediately follows the 12 byte header.

Converting to a .resx is just calling Convert.ToBase64String() on that image.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a partial answer -- There is a utility program available to do the extraction part.

> **GfxFromFrx**: How to extract graphics from VB binary property files

by Brad Martinez.

[image: example of utility in action]

It will extract resources in whatever format they are in - icon, bitmap, cursor, etc. and save to individual files.

Sources:

- Current: https://github.com/countingpine/gfxfromfrx
- The original location of this utility was here: [site](http://btmtz.mvps.org/gfxfromfrx/) and [code zip](http://btmtz.mvps.org/gfxfromfrx/gfxfromfrx.zip).
- It may no longer exist, but an archive is located here: [site](http://web.archive.org/web/20150815085919/http://btmtz.mvps.org/gfxfromfrx/) and [code zip](http://web.archive.org/web/20150815085919/http://btmtz.mvps.org/gfxfromfrx/gfxfromfrx.zip).

Comment: The source code is also on GitHub at: https://github.com/countingpine/gfxfromfrx

Comment: @ElizaBennet thanks! Updated the answer with that info.