# vb6 How to save the icon of image control or form of current project

Tags: vb6

I recovered my old project in visual basic but lost the pictures and icons, I found a way to save pictures inside of the controls into a file using the statement "SavePicture". Now, I am searching a way to save also the icons inside the controls or form of the current project. thanks for your help in advance, GBU :)

Comment: You mean other than the standard of storing icons for a toolbar, for example, in an imagelist control?

Comment: Why can't you use SavePicture for those also? `SavePicture Me.Icon, "c:\temp\" & Me.Name & ".ico"`

Comment: Does this help ([How do I extract images from a VB6 .frx file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45035961/3929185)?
Or this [Extract images from a VB project files](https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=5539&lngWId=1) ?